# The type 'wxMenuBar' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'wxMenuBarBase::GetLabelTop'

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, eclipse-cdt

I installed Eclipse and build the wxWidgets using the MinGW compiler using these tutorials:

http://max.berger.name/howto/wxWidgets/wxWidgets_Eclipse.jsp

When I try to run the wx hello world program it does compile and build the program and it actually works. But Eclipse is giving me the error:

> The type 'wxMenuBar' must implement the inherited pure virtual method
>   'wxMenuBarBase::GetLabelTop'

at the line:

```
wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
```

Is my environment being too demanding? Or how can I implement a pure virtual method?

Comment: I noticed right clicking the error in the Eclipse "Problems" pane made me able to change this error to be reported as a warning. But I don't know if that is such a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a problem with your wxWidgets source code.

Do a search in the wxwidgets installation folder for the file menu.cpp.  It should contain code something like:

```
wxString wxMenuBar::GetLabelTop(size_t pos) const
{
    wxCHECK_MSG( pos < GetMenuCount(), wxEmptyString,
                 wxT("invalid menu index in wxMenuBar::GetLabelTop") );

    return wxMenuItem::GetLabelFromText(m_titles[pos]);
}
```